# Using original or imputed datasets in analysis plan for survey data?

Tags: r, multiple-regression, missing-data, survey, multiple-imputation

I'm working with survey data that includes about 100 variables and about 3,500 respondents. Out of the 100 variables in the dataset, a lot of them had more than 5-10% missing data, and many were theoretically important

My problem was that entering each of those variables into a multiple regression model resulted in 30-40% of the cases being kicked out by listwise deletion. A biostatistician recommended using multiple imputation to handle the problem and generate a more reliable multiple regression model.

I'm new to multiple imputation. I read up on how to use predictive mean matching in the mice package in RStudio. I've generated a collection of imputed datasets and then get pooled estimates for a series of linear regression models. I'm wondering about the extent to which I should use the imputed dataset instead of the raw dataset for each step of the analytic plan.

For some context about what I'm reporting:

1. Table 1 - Demographics of the survey sample
2. Table 2 - Simple regression models that assess the association between each predictor and the primary outcome.
3. Table 3 - Multiple regression model that assesses the association between each influential predictor from Table 2 and the primary outcome.

I'm sure that I want to report the Table 3 model outputs with the pooled estimates from the imputed datasets. That was exactly what I did. However, I'm not sure if I should also use the pooled estimates in Tables 1 and 2. I'd rather use the raw data with the missing cells, especially for the categorical variables reported in Table 1. The categorical variables are also analyzed with no other contextual information in Table 2's simple regression model outputs.

Thoughts on the proper way to present these results and use imputed datasets? Should I use the imputed datasets for each analysis, or is it OK to just use the imputed datasets for one step of the analytic plan?